# Android, what is equivalent class of DrawerLayout when not using support library?

Tags: android, android-support-library, drawerlayout, android-compatibility

Since my minimum SDK version is 14, I don't want to add support library to my application.
Based on what Android says on [`DrawerLayout` page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html), this view group is defined in support library (`android.support.v4.widget`).

Is there any equivalent class of `DrawerLayout` if I don't add support library? Thanks.

Comment: I know that it doesn't actually answer your question, but I've used the SlidingMenu library for this and it works like a charm. If you don't want to use the library (as some changes to your code might be required), a look at its source code on GitHub might be of help to you. (https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

Comment: Thanks, yup, I did use it before for two of my projects. it's working fine but I have decided to explore more this recent drawer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, there is no alternative from within the AOSP code.
If you're using the `ViewPager` you'll need the support library anyways.